# How to select char between delimiters regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, char

I have an issue with a regex in javascript...

How can I select |test1| and |test2 word 1 any char| in

> word **|test1|** test word **|test2 word 1 any char|** test

?

The pipe char is the delimiter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
var string = 'word |test1| test word |test2 word 1 any char| test';
var data = string.match(/\|[^\|]*?\|/g) // match strings between delimiters
    .map(function (str) {
        return str.replace(/\|/g, ''); // remove delimiters
    });

console.log(data); // ["test1", "test2 word 1 any char"]
```

Comment: Same regex than jcubic but the m differed at the end :)

Comment: the `m` was just a mistake. the difference is the map function which removes the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = 'word |test1| test word |test2 word 1 any char| test';
alert(JSON.stringify(str.match(/\|[^|]+\|/g)));
```

Comment: Ok i'ts perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"word |test1| test word |test2 word 1 any char| test".match(/(\|.*?\|)/g)
```

let's explain it `/(\|.*?\|)/g`

- `()` is the capture group,
- `\| \|`  grab me what is between `|` and need to skip it as it has a different meaning in regex which is OR,
- `.*?` grab everything between them, and added `?` to say don't be greedy so it not give us somethings like `|a| |b|` as one but when it find the first pipe it can stop and start search for next,
- `g` at the end mean get all match not only the first; global search,
- `/(\|.*?\|)/g` all together

Comment: Thanks, 3 person at the same time for a similar regex, perfect lol

Comment: not the same @Jojoestar :) may be same result but not same syntax

Comment: Effectively, nice explanation:)